# Error en Boton Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

al ser nuevo estoy practicando en Android Studio, pero tengo un problema, he creado un boton y quiero largar un mensaje cuando este mismo sea presionado, pero me larga el siguiente error en una pantalla que solo puedo poner OK y no deja de salirse, osea que hago click en OK pero vuelve a aparecer. este es el error;

```
Cannot reload AVD list: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '360dpi' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, 280dpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
Error parsing C:\Users\NICOLAS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-23\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '360dpi' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, 280dpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
Error parsing C:\Users\NICOLAS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-23\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '360dpi' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, 280dpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
Error parsing C:\Users\NICOLAS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-23\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '360dpi' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, 280dpi, xhdpi, 400dpi, xxhdpi, 560dpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
Error parsing C:\Users\NICOLAS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-23\android-wear\x86\devices.xml
```

ESTA ES MI CLASE MAIN POR LAS DUDAS QUE LA NECESITEN

```
package schmidtnicolas.mixsdeideas;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button botonLogin;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    botonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    botonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

   switch (v.getId()){

       case R.id.button:
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Emtrando..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

}
```

}

A continuación presento la estructura de mi botón:

```
 Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_green"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:hint="Login"
        android:textColorHint="#97ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entra al SDK Manager y elimina los 2 paquetes mostrados en la imagen pero de la API 23 que son los que te arrojan el problema, si usas un AVD lo eliminas también y lo vuelves a crear:

[image: SDK Manager]

Comment: Excelente, problema resuelto. Muchas gracias.